# Does HC3 correction for unequal variances work in mixed ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

Since equal variances are necessary for any ANOVA that contains between-subject factors – regardless of whether it also contains within-subject factors – all such cases need correction (or alternative, e.g. robust tests). Based on my understanding of papers on the HC3 correction for unequal variances (e.g. [this](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/46617141/s0167-9473_2802_2900366-320160619-4909-lq55g5.pdf?1466345339=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DAsymptotic_inference_under_heteroskedast.pdf&Expires=1598617285&Signature=FUSG0gok4KW4iw27vMIRTWHWW1Tj76Auny%7Eaq3NpEGpxGKibr1SSy5E6kzGQotF--BSIqIo1PxGG-pfNEs32SZQyIlr1MopUPXUdGL121Z8AJXpDAnha1hGEFk%7E-RldtJCUOty3kFeaPyRpTzXCzqnJaHqIgJt3c2jy7RkUtrRlbZB5%7E%7EQ3hVMq%7E8QCkXKAegEdFv2SiO15VFXB8kzMSM-H2noStdP5nFxk-nrZ2l8EoDtSORhQPBd5KLfgPv9ngwG9te6K0Q0aXDwqnUFtpK5Ba2h4nxDZVbulpclSiS4dWsF1pFyzA6VQ3CUIpZSidCU2n5j3Gj2S%7E8T0YlsDppQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA) and [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2685594.pdf?casa_token=hH6wv4kwZd0AAAAA:6XfZUtD7YCu8qLonH-zE_9RnX4nKLgziaP_QbmqEYJvSZcMzOsgLaH-DItfwjjmA3hZLfnx2J7G4TGgzZIK61v2bZrJIcMPu9VckyA_lSOqBJdRn3cyIAg)), it would seem to me that in case of an equal variances assumption violation I can quite simply use this correction in any design, regardless of whether it contains any within-subject factors. So e.g. I can add [`white.adjust = "hc3"`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-8/topics/hccm) to any design in the [`aov()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aov) function in R, and unequal variances would be taken care of.

However, the [`ezANOVA` documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ez/versions/3.0-1/topics/ezANOVA) states the following:

> white.adjust
> **Only affects behaviour if the design contains only between-Ss predictor variables.**

Is this true? I cannot find any source that would either confirm or disprove this. If it is true, is there an easily implementable alternative correction for mixed-designs (or do I have to use robust methods)?